Why would a Xubuntu machine reboot after several minutes, even if boot from USB?
I have been using this machine successfully for 18 months.
It is dual-boot.
Under Windows I have zero problems.
Under Xubuntu, my primary use, the machine reboots after a few minutes of use.
This is true even if I boot up the machine from a Xubuntu 22.04 USB drive!!
I have tried with Xubuntu 24.04.01 as well as the original 22.04.2 ISO from when I first commissioned the machine.
Neither will work long enough for me to examine the log files of the installed Linux.
A hardware fault seems like the obvious answer, but Windows works perfectly happily.
Is it possible Xubuntu accesses a defective bit of hardware that Windows does not?
I would be grateful for any hints about how to track this down.
                         - o 0 o -

Processor   AMD Ryzen 9 6900HX with Radeon Graphics           3.30 GHz
Installed RAM   64.0 GB (63.3 GB usable)
